# Getting numbers from a string

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

```
Arsenal (0) - Swansea City (3)
```

The first step I want to get the numbers(0 and 3 in this case) the second step to delete from the string the (number).

Comment: Ok.  So what have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?  Did you read the PHP manual for [regex functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php)?

Comment: What should the String look at the end?

Comment: Arsenal - Swansea City- I'm not really familiar with regex, I tried the strpos but not really a god solution.

Comment: @Kicsi: If you're not familiar with regex, wouldn't the manual be a good place to start?  It has plenty of examples, and complete documentation for the syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

```
$myString = "Arsenal (0) - Swansea City (3)";
$newString = preg_replace_callback('/\d+/', function($match) {
    // The number matched is stored in $match, do whatever you need with it
    return ''; // Replace with nothing
}, $myString);
// $newString now contains "Arsenal () - Swansea City ()".
```

If you wanted to strip the `()` (and spaces) as well, modify the regular expression and your callback code:

```
'/\s*\(\d+\)/'
```